# The wireless internet does not work and the internet driver does not update

Tags: internet

The wireless internet does not work and the internet driver does not update. I have been trying for over 3 hours.

Comment: Not much for us to go on. Tell us... in those 3 hours what did you do and what did not work. Any errors? Any log files with information?

Answer (score 0):

What is your wireless card name details

You can find by running this

sudo lshw

Mostly default drivers should work , which driver you trying to install manually

System Settings > Software and Update > Additional drivers
Does it show any options for additional drivers?

Comment: Yes. I try to install it And it say "Could not install, Check Var>Reports>Jockey and i do, It Gibberish. I tried connect to either net.

Comment: When i did it said Check Jockey file i did Did not have anything. Really i tried and tried refreshing it. Just one error. I don't remember it, It was sent to the Empty Jockey file witch is still Empty.